# How to tell what is inside a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object.  If I just do an alert on it, it shows this: [object HTMLInputElement] but doesn't show the value.  If I do this

```
document.getElementById('rout_markers').value
```

then it shows nothing.  Does that mean it isn't set at all?  Whats the best way to check if it is null?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you just want to inspect the element for debugging purpose or do you need the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) is very good for this purpose. It has a [logging console](http://getfirebug.com/commandline) where you can inspect/debug javascript. So:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('rout_markers'));
```

and then enjoy the results in the console. It will contain answers to your questions.

Comment: you can also type in javascript commands on the console line.  Anyone who develops javascript should not be without it.

Comment: Most modern browsers have a form of a 'javascript console' that will work with this.  You don't have the use firefox/firebug.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, of course that you have to use FireBug. Not only for its logging functionality but for all other functionalities that *modern* browsers simply can't dream of.

Comment: Yep, chrome has a good one too, I just haven't found any tools that come close to all the power firebug has.  Chrome comes close, but I don't like it nearly as much.  But that is my own opinion.

Comment: @Zoidberg, yeah FireBug has been ported to Chrome, so indeed, Chrome has a good one too :-) Guys seriously if you are doing more than some recreational web development you should consider FireBug.

Comment: @Darin Awesome!  Chrome also has native tools that compare to firebug... but firebug is still much better (in my opinion).

Comment: of course, but for the purposes of this question, if the OP doesn't currently use Firefox he doesn't HAVE to switch browsers to use the given answer.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, the thing is that SO is not only for providing some answers, it's for providing suggestions for better development. The age of using `ifs` and `alerts` for debugging javascript is long time over. So if the OP is not using FireBug what I do with my answer is suggest him to switch browser and use it. So feel free to downvote my answer answer if you disagree with it you will also have to downvote the others as they are suggesting the same thing.

Comment: I have no problem with your opinion that firebug is superior, you ARE the only answer that suggests `console.log()` only works in firebug.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, did I write that `console.log` works only in `FireBug` in my answer? I just suggested a tool and a way to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is for debugging purposes

In that case I would suggest using

```
console.log(object);
```

This prints out a collapsable/expandable tree view of the entire object into your javascript console (firebug, chrome console, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Firefox (Firebug) or Google Chrome, you can do

```
console.log(document.getElementById('rout_markers'));
```